# Would "System" storage taking up 60 GB on High Sierra slow down my Mac?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, storage

I never configured Time Machine backups it so don’t think I have any in-place backups, however System reports it’s using HALF of my storage space and now my macbook's been working as slow as a snail.

- Model - MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015)
- Processor - 1.6 GHz Intel Core i5
- Memory - 4 GB1600 MHz DDR3
- Startup disk - Macintosh HD
- Graphics - Intel HD Graphics600 1536 MB
- macOS High Sierra - Version 10.13.5

[image]

Can I check that this isn’t making me slow?

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but the only way I ever got local TM backups to behave on High Sierra was to reformat the drive as HFS+ - ref: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326579/mac-pro-with-permanently-mounted-time-machine-local-snaps-any-benefit and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328358/recurring-volume-damage-time-machine-issues and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332079/apfs-high-sierra-tmutil-deletelocalsnapshots-will-not-delete-snapshots-error

Comment: A brighter outlook is that even the first Mojave public beta fixed it all & continues to behave on release... so that would be my actual suggestion for a 'fix'.

Comment: Hi - I've edited this to make it about slow. That's something that's easy to answer and we already have dozens of questions on how to determine what makes up "System" so that would likely get closed as a duplicate. Are you OK asking about speed? The answer is going to be that flash doesn't slow down due to capacity - it only slows down when it fails so deleting files won't help speed at all on Flash Storage.

Comment: Yeah I'm asking about the speed of the macbook. Thanks bmike. And I'm going to try doing the OS Mojave update and see what happens.

Comment: So just updated my macOS to the Mojave and yes the speed has improved but system storage is now 85 GB! It's increased by 15 GB and I think eventually, it's going to slow down my macbook again really soon.